# Newbie confusion about LINQ

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-objects

There are LINQ to SQL, LINQ to Entities and LINQ to Objects

What are the differences between all these and when to use which one?

I am new to all this stuff and trying to figure things out.

Are there perhaps schematic diagrams that can show me how each one works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQ is a language, LINQ to SQL, LINQ to Entities and LINQ to Objects (as well as Linq to XML, ...) are implementation that's enable you to apply Linq to various sources of data (database, collection of objects, xml, ...)

Look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb397926.aspx for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Linq 2 SQL is the quick and dirty ORM to use when you're short on time. Microsoft is phasing this out though. Linq to entities is more robust and is Microsofts preferred approach to data access. Linq to objects is completely different from the previous two it allows for the filtering, mapping and folding of in memory objects.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ is an extended programming component that added data query capability to .NET languages. There are rich of method names and query operators that you could use to work with different data structure e.g databases, classes, arrays

It came out in year 2007 , so in order to seamlessly work well with different data access, therefore you will heard that are different LINQ to [A-Z]

- LINQ to SQL - run time components to manage relational database
- LINQ to Entities - write queries against conceptual entity framework (ORM    Framework)
- LINQ to Objects - I would say "API" use within in .NET programming language to effective write  declarative code dealing with object structure in the classes/application.